# Printer OID does not work on every printer

Tags: snmp, printers, cmyk, oid

Hello I was asked to write a program to ask every printer in the network for there, name, location, and CMYK toners(how much percentage are left). I serched for the OID'a and everything was working. Now that i have the program that gets the data from all printers at some printers i does not work and the program shuts itself down. Why is that ?

Thanks in advance.
Yours sincerely Scarlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no common MIB to monitor all printers. So it is very vendor specific. There are several most commonly used MIBs to monitor printer devices:

- **PARALLEL-MIB** - MIB module for Parallel-printer-like hardware devices.
- **PRINTER-MIB** - MIB module for management of printers.
- **IANA-PRINTER-MIB** - IANA basic SNMP definitions for printer devices.
- **HP-LASERJET-COMMON-MIB** - Hewlett-Packard definitions for LaserJet series devices.

Comment: I have Konica Minolta Printer. So what is the best i can use that i works for mostly everyone ?

Comment: The base OID for Konika Minolta is 1.3.6.1.4.1.18334. So try searching for MIB files based on that.

Comment: Thank alot, again :)